# Mistakes made in acs application

Tags: visa, immigration, australia

I submitted my acs application but while uploading reference letters, I uploaded statutory declaration under reference heading.

So is that a big mistake and cannot be corrected.

Comment: What country is this for?

Comment: This is for australia

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be ok (you might be asked to resubmit it to proper catgory although I doubt they will bother, they seem to be lenient in regards to applicant ignorance), at first I have submitted not notarised copies of my references and diploma they came back with following letter:

[image]

Basically they gave me a month to fix the mess I have made (while they could have taken the money and rejected), which is much appreciated...

**EDIT:** It is worth noting that IMMI is not as professional or forgiving as ACS so thread carefully...